# Using Vlookup for conditional matching

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Hello I am learning `VLookUp` but I don't know how can we cover this case. Can someone guide me what changes should be made in my formula, I want to fill in "Healthy/UnHealthy" after looking the `Average` value.

[Sheet Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbYuo.png)

Pardon me if this is not right site to ask this question, if not them guide me where should I ask this?

Comment: Try if(value>=average,"Healthy","Unhealthy") but not tested as I am on my smartphone. Note you may need to use <= depending on what your value is and how it compares to average...

Answer (score 1):

You need an IF statement to provide an answer

In the `N2` place formula

```
=IF(M2>=2500,"Healthy","Unhealthy")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your data in column S to actual numbers you can use `INDEX` and `MATCH`:
`healthy` value: `2500` in `S4`
`unhealthy` value: `0` in `S5`
(You can choose to use custom formatting to have the data the same appearance: `">="#,##0; ">="-#,##0; "<2500`. I was unable to test this custom formatting works correctly, since I'm working from my phone).

Than use and drag down the following formula in `N2`:
`=INDEX($R$4:$R$5,MATCH(TRUE,($S$4:$S$5<=$M2),0))`

If you would want the same for the Body Type, change the data in column S to numbers following the same logic as above (value for Obese should be 0) and format these cells with custom formatting: `">="#,##0; ">="-#,##0; "<2600`

Than use and drag down the following formula in `O2`:
`=INDEX($R$8:$R$12,MATCH(TRUE,($S$8:$S$12<=$M2),0))`